# \citep for multiple references separated by text

Tags: biblatex

For 2 references, how would I produce textual citations such that

> Statement (species A: author1 date1; species B: ref2)

I tried `\citep[species A:][]{ref1}[species B:][]{ref2}`, but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: In that case you better use `\parencites[species A:][]{ref1}[species B:][]{ref2}` (notice the **`s`**). The `natbib` compatibility commands are just wrappers around their `biblatex` counterparts (so `\citep` is actually a `\parencite`; there are exceptions for the starred versions) and do not have multi-cite support (as indeed `natbib` does not).

Comment: Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: @moewe ^^^^ ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B There you are.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a multi-cite version of `\citep`. That does not really exist, but since `biblatex`'s `natbib` commands are just wrappers around their standard counterparts, `\citep` is really `\parencite` (exceptions apply for the starred versions: `\citep*` is not `\parencite*`, it is `\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}\parencite`). The multi-cite version for `\parencite` is `\parencites`, so you want

```
\parencites[species A:][]{ref1}[species B:][]{ref2}
```

Comment: old thread, but this doesn't seem to work with nature style biblatex? `\parencites{cite1, cite2}[see][for review]{cite3}` produced weird ([cite 1, cite2]; [see cite3 for review])

Comment: @Sharah I get "[1, 2, see 3, for review]". If it does not work for you, please open a new question with an MWE, the output you get and the output you expect to see instead. I seem to remember you are using Overleaf and as I pointed out before their package versions are slowly becoming outdated. So it may well be that this was a bug in the package that has been fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write:

```
(species A: \citealp{ref1}; species B: \citealp{ref2})
```

It's more readable.

Comment: Since this appears to be more of a parenthetical citation, I'd probably go with `\citealp` instead of `\citealt`, but at least with `biblatex` there shouldn't be a difference. Note that sometimes it can be beneficial to make sure that all citations in one parenthesis are produced by the same cite command, in which case the `\parencites` approach would produce better results (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576752/35864).