# biblatex: Controlling ibid on the instance level

Tags: biblatex, natbib, biber

*ibid.* is an awesome `biblatex` feature but there are some (rare) occasions where I would like to deactivate it, for a given citation at a given location.

Take for example the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear-icomp,maxcitenames=4,mincitenames=1,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{;\space}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}

\noindent or from socio-political pressures (cf.\ \citealp[45]{chandler2007a}; 
\citealp[27]{fontana2003a}). A~general pattern is noticed in a given social context: as a 
culture increases in longevity, there is a tendency to regard the beliefs of previous 
generations as being \emph{archaic} or \emph{superstitious}. Their symbols are rationalized and 
sanitized, interpreted literally or simply abandoned altogether by the next cultural elite. 
Deprived of their context, such symbols diminish in power and have to be rediscovered afresh 
\citep[28]{fontana2003a}.

\end{document}
```

with the following records:

```
@book{fontana2003a,
  author = {Fontana, David},
  year = {2003},
  title = {The Secret Language of Symbols: A Visual Key to Symbols and their Meanings},
  publisher = {Chronicle Books LLC},
  address = {San Francisco},
}
@book{chandler2007a,
  author = {Chandler, Daniel},
  year = {2007},
  title = {Semiotics: The Basics},
  publisher = {Routledge, Taylor \& Francis Group},
  address = {London, New York},
}
```

which gives:
[image]

The author of the text complained that the *ibid.* is ambiguous. Technically Fontana is the last author mentioned, *but* since Chandler and Fontana are given in the same parenthesis, when the eye goes six lines up to find the last citation, there is a doubt, sufficient to slow down reading.

It would be nice if I could just use a command like `\noibidcitealp[28]{fontana2003a}` or maybe `{\donotuseibid\citealp[29]{fontana2003a}}`. Is this possible? (Reminder: **I do not wish to deactivate *ibid.* globally**, I would like to deactivate **only for this very specific citation**.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\mancite`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear-icomp,maxcitenames=4,mincitenames=1,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{;\space}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}

\noindent or from socio-political pressures (cf.\ \citealp[45]{chandler2007a};
\citealp[27]{fontana2003a}). A~general pattern is noticed in a given social context: as a
culture increases in longevity, there is a tendency to regard the beliefs of previous
generations as being \emph{archaic} or \emph{superstitious}. Their symbols are rationalized and
sanitized, interpreted literally or simply abandoned altogether by the next cultural elite.
Deprived of their context, such symbols diminish in power and have to be rediscovered afresh
\mancite\citep[28]{fontana2003a}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ulrike!

Answer (score 2):

Ulrike has already shown you how you can manually suppress a "ibid." with `\mancite`, but in this case you won't actually have to do that if you generate your first citation parentheses with a single `biblatex` command.

```
(cf.\ \citealp[45]{chandler2007a}; \citealp[27]{fontana2003a})
```

can be replaced by

```
\parencites[cf.][45]{chandler2007a}[27]{fontana2003a}
```

If you use a single command to cite several entries at once, `biblatex` automatically considers a subsequent use of "ibid." ambiguous and avoids it (this can be changed by setting the option `ibidtracker` to a different value).

So the following just works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxcitenames=4, mincitenames=1,
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}
\renewcommand\compcitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{fontana2003a,
  author    = {Fontana, David},
  year      = {2003},
  title     = {The Secret Language of Symbols},
  subtitle  = {A Visual Key to Symbols and their Meanings},
  publisher = {Chronicle Books LLC},
  address   = {San Francisco},
}
@book{chandler2007a,
  author    = {Chandler, Daniel},
  year      = {2007},
  title     = {Semiotics: The Basics},
  publisher = {Routledge, Taylor \& Francis Group},
  address   = {London, New York},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent or from socio-political pressures \parencites[cf.][45]{chandler2007a}[27]{fontana2003a}.
A~general pattern is noticed in a given social context: as a 
culture increases in longevity, there is a tendency to regard the beliefs of previous 
generations as being \emph{archaic} or \emph{superstitious}. Their symbols are rationalized and 
sanitized, interpreted literally or simply abandoned altogether by the next cultural elite. 
Deprived of their context, such symbols diminish in power and have to be rediscovered afresh 
\citep[28]{fontana2003a}.
\end{document}
```

[image: (cf. Chandler, 2007, p. 45; Fontana, 2003, p. 27) ... (Fontana, 2003, p. 28)]

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, but how many citations can I add in a `\parencites` ? It gets quite complicated…

Comment: @yannis As many as you want. Each citation can have its own pre- and postnote. You can also have a global pre- and postnote. The general syntax is `\parencites(<global pre>)(<global post>)[<pre_1>][<post_1>]{<key_{1,1}>,...,<key_{1,m_1}>}[<pre_2>][<post_2>]{<key_{2,1}>,...,<key_{2,m_2}>}...[<pre_n>][<post_n>]{<key_{n,1}>,...,<key_{n,m_n}>}`.

Comment: This is very very very nice indeed because I'm really tired of typing `\citealp`, but how can I get this behavior for `\citet`?

Comment: @yannis `\textcites`